# UIPanGestureRecognizer detect when one object cross another object

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for move my `UIView` objects on the screen.

**What I want to do**
The main purpose is figure out how can I catch event when two objects cross each other. For example two UIView objects. So first one it's static object (that don't move) and another one I can move on the screen when I want it. Therefore I need to know a moment when my second object (UIView) cross a static object. Also main problem is that these views are located on different views. So first static view is located on view that is called "edit view" and another view is located on view that is called as "tool bar". So that's means that I can't just compare two rect and enjoy it. Is there any way how to compare two object when they cross each other, but maybe without method that just compare they rect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is UIView's convertRect:toView: method.

```
CGRect *convertedView1Rect = [view1 convertRect:view1.frame toView:view2];
BOOL intersects = CGRectIntersection(convertedView1Frame, view2.frame);
```

Comment: Thanks it's what I need, but I add a little correction.
CGRect convertedViewFromTools = [self.view convertRect:viewFromTools.frame fromView:viewFromTools.superview];       CGRect intersects = CGRectIntersection(convertedViewFromTools, vc.view.frame);
BOOL isIntersected = intersects.size.height > 0;

Answer (score 1):

```
   Following method required two parameter of rectangle's - just pass rect1 and rect2 , and it return bool value whether it intersect or not - 

   if( CGRectIntersectsRect(<#CGRect rect1#>, <#CGRect rect2#>) ) {
         NSLog("Intersect");
    } else {
         NSLog("Not Intersect");
     }
```

Comment: thanks, yes there is something what I want, but as I said these are different views and I can't just compare. Because I can make it operation if both view are located on the one view.